# How can I set a 410 redirect in htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, aspx

I recently upgraded a website from aspx to a drupal site. I never <del>310'd</del> 301'd the old pages which are gone.

The old aspx pages are still showing up as 404 error in google webmaster. I have created a new site map for the drupal site when it was launched 2 months ago, and then again recently.

Can I create a 410 redirect in the htaccess for all aspx pages like a wildcard? If so how can I do this?
thanks in advance

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set `410 Gone` as redirect, which indicates that the web server has no forwarding address for the URL and the browsers would treat it as error. You should use `301 Move Permanently` instead, using below line in .htaccess would redirect like wildcat to newsite.com

```
  Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

Comment: HI so Redirect 301 is essentially the old asp pages, redirecting to the same domain which now hosts the drupal site?

Comment: Presumably the newsite is still hosted on the same domain? In which case you can't simply `Redirect` all files to the "newsite" quite in this way.

Comment: `RedirectMatch .*\.asp$ /` would redirect all .asp pages to the root of your site in the same domain